# Deploy AWS SageMaker pipeline using the cloud development kit (CDK)

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-cdk, amazon-sagemaker

I'm looking to deploy the SageMaker pipeline using CDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_sagemaker.CfnPipeline.html) but could not find any code examples. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDK L1 Constructs correspond 1:1 to a CloudFormation resource of the same name. The construct props match the resouce properties.  The go-to source is therefore the CloudFormation docs.

The `AWS::SageMaker::Pipeline` [docs have a more complete example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sagemaker-pipeline.html#aws-resource-sagemaker-pipeline--examples).

Comment: Thanks, @fedonev! Would you say `sagemaker pipeline` is not supported yet using CDK?

Comment: @Ulkurz It is supported.  It's implemented in the CDK as a [L1 Construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_lib), which simply means you must work with the low-level CloudFormation-type properties, without the helpful abstractions that CDK L2 and L3 Constructs provide.

Comment: Great, thanks again @fedonev! Would you say that we could perhaps use Python-SDK to codify the sagemaker pipeline in a more developer-friendly fashion, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70191757/7722929)? We can then use `pipeline.definition()` to build a JSON that could be used with CloudFormation. Is this a viable approach?

Comment: @Ulkurz Yes, absolutely.  Adding abstractions using language features is a CDK superpower!

Comment: @fedonev, if one is primarily driven by an interest in using CDK, it sounds like SageMaker pipelines might not be any easier than defining vanilla StepFunctions with CDK, instead. Is that a fair assessment?

Answer (score 0):

pipeline.definition() outputs the needed cloudformation content... as noted above, there is not yet cdk support for L1 services.