# SageMaker pipelines CDK: All steps defined in Python script

Tags: python, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I'm interested in using SageMaker pipelines for the full ML Life cycle. From [AWS SageMaker Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-steps.html) I see that discrete steps can be defined in python, such steps could include Processing, Training, Tuning, RegisterModel, etc.

What I'd like to better understand is how to define such a SageMaker pipeline using CDK? Ideally, the CDK would not explicitly define discrete steps, containerization of code/packages for each step, etc. But rather, the CDK would point to a python package (or script) that contains these discrete steps.

The advantage of such a design is that one could add or remove steps using Python alone without making any changes to CDK, diffs on the relevant python package/script would bubble up, mutating the SageMaker pipeline.

Pessimistically, I anticipate that there is a 1:1 relationship between steps defined in python and configurations declared in CDK. However, based on this documentation, I think it might be possible fr CDK to define an abstract pipeline where the specific steps are purely a function of python code.

Questions

1. Is this possible or am I overly optimistic about ML Ops automation using SageMaker pipelines?
2. Could you link a resource, tutorial, etc. that demonstrates the CDK resource declarations that would realize such a design? (The specific python steps don't matter, so long as Python *alone* is defining the steps and sequence.)

Comment: Have you seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203674/deploy-aws-sagemaker-pipeline-using-the-cloud-development-kit-cdk ?

Comment: @MarcKarp, I checked this out. Unfortunately, it's still ambiguous to me where this Python code (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/build-and-manage-steps.html#step-type-processing) should be hosted. To me, it seems intuitive that a CDK one-liner would point a python package entrypoint. But I can't seem to find this design pattern demonstrated anywhere, so perhaps this isn't possible.

Comment: Maybe I’m overthinking it and simply pushing code changes to a Python repo would cause underlying Sagemaker resources to build/deploy similar to code changes on a CDK package.